# How to say that you have a blog in Russian?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I have a slovar and I have asked people I know but I get all kind of answers. How to say in Russian: "I have a blog".

Comment: "I am in prison for crimes against the state" usually works.

Comment: @Sycorax Is that an Alexei Navalny reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`У меня есть блог` appears to be the most exact translation. `Я веду блог` is also an option. The latter variant is even closer to English `I have...` clause and it sounds natural to Russian, unlike literal translation `Я имею блог`. Please do not use `я имею...` in this case.

If your intend to introduce yourself as a blogger in an oral conversation, then just `я - блоггер` (`I'm a blogger`) will be OK.

Comment: *Я веду...* is only grammatically closer to *I have...* than *У меня есть...*, but semantically it's certainly the other way round.

Comment: What is a good way to say that you have many followers. Would followers in this case be synonym with: "последователи"?

Comment: @Ева: "Follower" in this sense is more like "подписчик" in Russian. To avoid confusion with the "subscriber" variation of the meaning, however, it seems that Russian language has adopted a transliteration: [фолловер](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/фолловер). (A Wiktionary entry may not necessarily be an indication of actual adoption of a word, but you will certainly get quite a number of hits if you try googling it.)

Comment: @Andriy M: Many thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Sergey Would it not be enough to just say `У меня блог` because I learned that `есть` always implies that you carry the actual thing with you. For example your mobile phone or a pen would be with `есть` because you have it with you and vice versa.

Comment: @SilvingsQuantu you cannot omit predicator having dependent clause parts. *"У меня"* is an adverbial of place: *"есть (где? у кого?) - у меня"*.

Answer (score 5):

To answer by Sergey I'd also add that you'd rather use `Я веду блог` if you want to imply that you're an active blogger, because `У меня есть блог` may also mean that you have a blog, but you are not posting actively or even abandoned it.